# Is there a way to query two indexes and join the result in Opensearch/ElasticSearch (Just like we do in RDBMS)

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

My requirement is

- I have a deeply nested filter condition
- Params from filter condition is located in two elastic search indexes
- I need to pass the filter condition as query and get results which are joined by a field

The existing way is to use two indexes comma separated and searching but is supports only `or` - `should` condition. Reference : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/query-multiple-indexes-but-apply-queries-to-specific-index/127858

I need a way to support to `and` - `must` condition also.

Is there a possibility to do that? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try to create an alias on the two indices?